# What is the maximum possible identicons count on GitHub?

Tags: math, github, hash, avatar

GitHub provides default identicons as the profile picture. You can get one for your account too, [like this](https://github.com/identicons/pravj.png).

There are many [other implementations](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=identicon) on GitHub, using the similar way and producing similar results.

In their implementation they choose to color some of the 25 tiles and then use one color to fill for all the non-blank tiles. Let's assume that they use a total of 20 colors to fill the tiles, they don't use this much colors, though.

This way, the maximum possible identicon count seems to be **20 x 2<sup>15</sup>** only, as they reflect the identicon with the vertical axis and use only **15** tiles to generate an identicon.

Now, **20 x 2<sup>15</sup> = 655360** is a very low number compared to total number of users on GitHub.

So my question is that, is there a *definite* collision situation in this case or am I missing something?

Comment: I think this would be better suited on the Mathematics site as it is not programming related

Comment: Should I migrate it there?